# Deploying Spring Boot Application in Google Cloud with external files referenced within build

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud. I developed an application in Java Spring Boot and executed it in my local. It is working fine. My application is created in such a way, it references to a text file outside the jar location. In my local, when I place it in the target folder, it is executing without any error.

In google cloud, I created storage and uploaded the JAR file along with the reference text file. I deployed this build on an app engine and I am getting successful response for few requests. But, when I make a request that requires this text file, I am getting an error in Google Cloud shell logs - file not found in the workspace.

How should I place the reference files in Cloud so that it is referenced by my build? Please let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: Add the logs plz

Comment: I'm not sure to catch you. In your last question `How should I place the reference files in Cloud so that it is referenced by my build?`, what is the Cloud? Cloud Storage? And you talk about `Build`. But just before you said that you have built your Jar and deployed it on App Engine. Your concern is at build phase? Deployment phase? In addition, how did you deployed on App Engine? Can you also describe this part?

Comment: Please, provide the stack trace that you are seeing in the logs. Besides that, include more details in the request that you are making.